# Derivation of Correlation function in Open Quantum Systems and Master Equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, quantum-optics, correlation-functions, open-quantum-systems

I have a question and I have searched a long time about it without any success. It is about how to include convolution broadening incorrelation functions of bath operators, when using Open Quantum Systems formalism.
So we have given Hamiltonian from this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.6632
$$H=\sum_m \omega_m a^{\dagger}_m a_m+\sum_i \frac{\omega_D}{2}\sigma_i^z+\Omega b_i^{\dagger}b_i+g(a_m\sigma_i^{\dagger}D_i+a^{\dagger}_m\sigma_i D_i^{\dagger})$$
Here $D_i$ is a Displacement operator, which reads $D_i=e^{2\sqrt{S}(b_i^{\dagger}-b_i)}$. When they derive a master equation for density matrix, they treat operators $D_i$ as a bath with interaction strength $g$ and $a^{\dagger}_m\sigma_i$ operators as system operators. I have calculated master equation myself and when I get to the correlation functions, I find them to be of sorts:
$$K(\delta)=g^2\int\limits_0^{\infty} dt \, \langle(D_i^{\dagger}(t)D_i(0)\rangle e^{i(\omega_m-\omega_D)t} $$
However, in paper they have found this integral to be
$$K(\delta)=g^2\int\limits_0^{\infty}  dt \, \langle(D_i^{\dagger}(t)D_i(0)\rangle e^{-(\Gamma_{\uparrow}+\Gamma_{\downarrow})|t|}e^{i(\omega_m-\omega_D)t} $$
where $\Gamma_{\uparrow},\Gamma_{\downarrow}$ are pump and decay rates. How did they manage to include this additional term? Could it be derived from the final master equation which reads:
[image]

It is worth noting, that terms with $\kappa, \Gamma_{\uparrow},\Gamma_{\downarrow}$ were just added phenomenologically. From original Hamiltonian only $\Gamma(\pm\delta_m)$ terms emerge naturally.

Comment: The paper you cite gives a reference to a paper where it takes this equation from: https://journals.aps.org/prl/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevLett.107.093901 (reference 51 in the paper). Does that help at all?

Comment: I was thinking to include that paper also in my question. I can not find a satisfactory answer in that paper as well.